# Lat/lng coordinates to 3D images

Tags: api, 3d, maps, google-earth

I have a number of lat/lng coordinates that I would like to show 3D images for.

Google Earth API seems to have been closed, so does anyone know if another API I can use?

The coordinates I have are for cities all over the world.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If want to display data on a 3D globe then [CesiumJS](https://cesiumjs.org/) is your best alternative to Google Earth API. Cesium is an open-source geospatial visualization JavaScript library for creating web-based 3D globe applications. It requires no browser plugins and is cross-platform and cross-device. Cesium uses [WebGL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebGL) for graphic rendering which has been adopted by all major web browsers.

See the online demos to get a sense of what it can do:

- https://cesiumjs.org/demos.html

There is an online "Sandcastle" application that has a gallery of code examples and runs the code in the web-browser. You can also change the code on-the-fly and re-run with your changes to test out using the Cesium API.

- https://cesiumjs.org/Cesium/Apps/Sandcastle/index.html

If you have experience using Google Earth API then there are a number of tutorials and examples showing how to migrate to Cesium:

- https://cesiumjs.org/for-google-earth-developers.html

Comment: Great. Thanks a lot.